# Can Visual Studio Page Inspector cause High CPU issues?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, cpu-usage, page-inspector

I'm working on a asp.Net MVC 4 application that's on top of a Domain Model Architecture.

Everything is fine a part that since a couple of days (upgraded many common packages) when I start the debugging session I can see the CPU getting higher and higher without any (apparent) reason: the application in the browser is still perfectly responsive.

Exactly the same source code, if configured as "Release", works perfectly and I don't experience any CPU raise.

I tested the same code on two more machines (Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 7) and everything works fine (no matters if Debug or Release).

I ended up creating many memory dumps on my machine (Win 8.1) and this is briefly what I found spending a couple of days on testing and monitoring:

http://screencast.com/t/hJa1V1V5ej

So even if I was not running the Page Inspector within Visual Studio, it seems that for some reason Page Inspector was performing some operation in the background...

I'm actually reinstalling Visual Studio to see if in some way can get rid of the problem, hoping I'm on the right path.

Any idea would be really appreciated.

**UPDATE**

To workaround the issue I renamed the folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Page Inspector

to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Page InspectorBLABLA.

In this way Visual Studio is no longer able to load the PageInspector libraries and the issue doesn't show up. So no high CPU no slowdowns. Of course I'm getting a couple of errors when VS launches: 'Eureka package didn't load correctly' and another more generic one.

I'm going to install the latest VS update to see if the issue has been solved.

Comment: I do not have a direct solution to this, but the reason I found your post is the fact that I have started to notice that my PC slowdowns seem to start happening when I fire up PageInspector in VS 2013, although no obvious CPU hogging like you say.  I am also using Resharper, are you?

Comment: Hi, yes I'm using reshaper as well. I just updated the Question adding the workaround I found. It seems that it's not related to Resharper. I also tried on another machine without reshaper and the issue was showing.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue, and disabling "Browser Link" fixed it. You can see how [here](http://www.poconosystems.com/software-development/how-to-disable-browser-link-in-visual-studio-2013/).

Comment: Hi Jason, I'll give it a try and let you know! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but with Browser Link, I solved renaming the folder

> ...\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Browser Link

Comment: With Visual Studio 2022 Preview